# JBOSS not finding my project's Maven Dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, jersey-1.0

I am running a MAVEN app inside JBOSS AS 5.1 that has a jersey-server dependency. This is my pom.xml entry for the dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Simple, right? Here is my web.xml for the project which points to the Servlet Container that exists within this jar.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyAPI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>        
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>edu.emory.clinical.trials.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyAPI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Although the server starts up fine, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` when I attempt to hit the configured @Path. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE, and I can clearly see the class is generated in the maven repository dependency structure (.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/...).

I'm a bit new to Maven, so I'm sure there must be something basic I am missing, but it doesn't appear that JBOSS is recognizing my project's runtime dependencies that I've declared in the POM. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `<scope>runtime</scope>` is going to be your problem. Look into the `<scope>` tags.